# Best practice for importing modules that contain imports

Tags: python, import, module

I tried to break up one large file into three smaller files for organization purposes and now nothing works.  I'm sure the problem is with my import statements. Main.py imports Members.py and Members imports from RouteTools.  However, even after including

```
import routeTools
...routeTools.tool()
```

In Members.py, it doesn't work after

```
Main.py
import Members
...Members.stuff()
```

I even tried putting

```
import routeTools
```

at the top of `Main.py` as well.  What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to organize one file into multiple modules?  Thanks.

Edit: "nothing works" = `NameError: global name 'tool' is not defined` when running `routeTools.tool()` from Members.py after it has been imported into `Main.py`

Here is my code:

```
import routetools

class Member(object):
    def __init__(self, fields, scouts, id):
        ...
        self.routes = [routeTools.Route(s) for s in self.scouts ]
        ...
```

And this is called in `Main.py`:

```
import Members
import routeTools 

...
member = Members.Member(self.fields, self.scouts, i)
```

`routeTools` contains:

```
class Route(object):
    ...
```

Comment: What does it mean _now nothing works_? What's the error you're getting? Also, do you have a file called `Main.py` whose first line is `import Members` or do you have a file whose first line is actually `Main.py`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that.  `NameError: global name 'tool' is not defined` if I were to try `routeTools.tool()`

Comment: It sounds like the `routeTools` module doesn't have a `tool` function, or somewhere in your code you're calling `tool()` without doing `from routeTools import tool` Can you provide more context? How does the line where this fails looks like?

Comment: Try adding `from routeTools import tool` and paste the result?

Comment: For questions like this, it helps tremendously if you post your package structure. We are flying blind otherwise, and most likely can't help without it.

Comment: you have no tools in routeTools.py

Comment: Sorry, updated to include code.

Comment: @oxymor0n I am not sure what you mean by package structure.  This is the first time I have attempted to split up a large file into modules, so maybe I am going about this wrong?

Comment: @josibake package structure is the directory tree of your Python package. Kind of like directory tree, if that makes sense. [This article](http://axialcorps.com/2013/08/29/5-simple-rules-for-building-great-python-packages/) might be a good reference.